# Помогите скрыть элемент в Битрикс при отсутствие товара

Tags: php, битрикс

На сайте при отсутствие товара дня остается пустой блок. Помогите с условием, чтоб скрывалась, когда не было товара.

`

```
<div class="offers">
    <div class="block-center-wide">
        <div class="offers__inner">
            <div class="offers__block offers__block-product_day">

                <? $GLOBALS["arrFilter"] = [
                    ">PROPERTY_DAY_PRODUCT" => date("Y-m-d"),
                    '!PROPERTY_ARCHIVE' => 
\Oneway\Constants::ID_PROP_ARCHIVE_YES
                ];?>

                <? $APPLICATION->IncludeComponent("oneway:catalog.section", 
    "day_product_index", Array(
                    "IBLOCK_TYPE" => "catalog", // Тип инфоблока
                    "IBLOCK_ID" => \Oneway\Constants::IBLOCK_CATALOG,   // Инфоблок
                    "SECTION_ID" => "", // ID раздела
                    "SECTION_CODE" => "",   // Код раздела
                    "SECTION_USER_FIELDS" => array( // Свойства раздела
                        0 => "",
                        1 => "",
                    ),
                    "ELEMENT_SORT_FIELD" => "PROPERTY_DAY_PRODUCT", // По какому полю сортируем элементы
                    "ELEMENT_SORT_ORDER" => "asc",  // Порядок сортировки элементов
                    "ELEMENT_SORT_FIELD2" => "timestamp_x", // Поле для второй сортировки элементов
                    "ELEMENT_SORT_ORDER2" => "asc", // Порядок второй сортировки элементов
                    "FILTER_NAME" => "arrFilter",   // Имя массива со значениями фильтра для фильтрации элементов
                    "INCLUDE_SUBSECTIONS" => "Y",   // Показывать элементы подразделов раздела
                    "SHOW_ALL_WO_SECTION" => "Y",   // Показывать все элементы, если не указан раздел
                    "HIDE_NOT_AVAILABLE" => "Y",    // Не отображать товары, которых нет на складах
                    "PAGE_ELEMENT_COUNT" => "1",    // Количество элементов на странице
                    "LINE_ELEMENT_COUNT" => "1",    // Количество элементов выводимых в одной строке таблицы
                    "PROPERTY_CODE" => array(   // Свойства
                        0 => "",
                        1 => "",
                    ),
                    "OFFERS_LIMIT" => "0",  // Максимальное количество предложений для показа (0 - все)
                    "ADD_PICT_PROP" => "-",
                    "LABEL_PROP" => "-",
                    "PRODUCT_SUBSCRIPTION" => "N",  // Разрешить оповещения для отсутствующих товаров
                    "SHOW_DISCOUNT_PERCENT" => "N", // Показывать процент скидки
                    "SHOW_OLD_PRICE" => "Y",    // Показывать старую цену
                    "SHOW_CLOSE_POPUP" => "N",  // Показывать кнопку продолжения покупок во всплывающих окнах
                    "MESS_BTN_BUY" => "Купить", // Текст кнопки "Купить"
                    "MESS_BTN_ADD_TO_BASKET" => "В корзину",    // Текст кнопки "Добавить в корзину"
                    "MESS_BTN_SUBSCRIBE" => "Подписаться",  // Текст кнопки "Уведомить о поступлении"
                    "MESS_BTN_COMPARE" => "Сравнить",   // Текст кнопки "Сравнить"
                    "MESS_BTN_DETAIL" => "Подробнее",   // Текст кнопки "Подробнее"
                    "MESS_NOT_AVAILABLE" => "Нет в наличии",    // Сообщение об отсутствии товара
                    "SECTION_URL" => "",    // URL, ведущий на страницу с содержимым раздела
                    "DETAIL_URL" => "", // URL, ведущий на страницу с содержимым элемента раздела
                    "SECTION_ID_VARIABLE" => "SECTION_ID",  // Название переменной, в которой передается код группы
                    "AJAX_MODE" => "N", // Включить режим AJAX
                    "AJAX_OPTION_JUMP" => "N",  // Включить прокрутку к началу компонента
                    "AJAX_OPTION_STYLE" => "N", // Включить подгрузку стилей
                    "AJAX_OPTION_HISTORY" => "N",   // Включить эмуляцию навигации браузера
                    "CACHE_TYPE" => "A",    // Тип кеширования
                    "CACHE_TIME" => "36000000", // Время кеширования (сек.)
                    "CACHE_GROUPS" => "N",  // Учитывать права доступа
                    "SET_TITLE" => "N", // Устанавливать заголовок страницы
                    "SET_BROWSER_TITLE" => "N", // Устанавливать заголовок окна браузера
                    "SET_META_KEYWORDS" => "N", // Устанавливать ключевые слова страницы
                    "SET_META_DESCRIPTION" => "Y",  // Устанавливать описание страницы
                    "META_DESCRIPTION" => "-",  // Установить описание страницы из свойства
                    "ADD_SECTIONS_CHAIN" => "N",    // Включать раздел в цепочку навигации
                    "SET_STATUS_404" => "N",    // Устанавливать статус 404, если не найдены элемент или раздел
                    "CACHE_FILTER" => "Y",  // Кешировать при установленном фильтре
                    "ACTION_VARIABLE" => "action",  // Название переменной, в которой передается действие
                    "PRODUCT_ID_VARIABLE" => "id",  // Название переменной, в которой передается код товара для покупки
                    "PRICE_CODE" => array(  // Тип цены
                        0 => "BASE",
                    ),
                    "USE_PRICE_COUNT" => "N",   // Использовать вывод цен с диапазонами
                    "SHOW_PRICE_COUNT" => "1",  // Выводить цены для количества
                    "PRICE_VAT_INCLUDE" => "Y", // Включать НДС в цену
                    "CONVERT_CURRENCY" => "N",  // Показывать цены в одной валюте
                    "BASKET_URL" => "/personal/basket.php", // URL, ведущий на страницу с корзиной покупателя
                    "USE_PRODUCT_QUANTITY" => "N",  // Разрешить указание количества товара
                    "ADD_PROPERTIES_TO_BASKET" => "N",  // Добавлять в корзину свойства товаров и предложений
                    "ADD_TO_BASKET_ACTION" => "ADD",    // Показывать кнопку добавления в корзину или покупки
                    "DISPLAY_COMPARE" => "N",   // Разрешить сравнение товаров
                    "PAGER_TEMPLATE" => ".default", // Шаблон постраничной навигации
                    "DISPLAY_TOP_PAGER" => "N", // Выводить над списком
                    "DISPLAY_BOTTOM_PAGER" => "N",  // Выводить под списком
                    "PAGER_TITLE" => "Товары",  // Название категорий
                    "PAGER_SHOW_ALWAYS" => "N", // Выводить всегда
                    "PAGER_DESC_NUMBERING" => "N",  // Использовать обратную навигацию
                    "PAGER_DESC_NUMBERING_CACHE_TIME" => "36000",   // Время кеширования страниц для обратной навигации
                    "PAGER_SHOW_ALL" => "N",    // Показывать ссылку "Все"
                    "AJAX_OPTION_ADDITIONAL" => "", // Дополнительный идентификатор
                    "BROWSER_TITLE" => "-", // Установить заголовок окна браузера из свойства
                    "META_KEYWORDS" => "-", // Установить ключевые слова страницы из свойства
                    "PRODUCT_QUANTITY_VARIABLE" => "quantity",  // Название переменной, в которой передается количество товара
                    "PRODUCT_PROPS_VARIABLE" => "prop", // Название переменной, в которой передаются характеристики товара
                    "PARTIAL_PRODUCT_PROPERTIES" => "N",    // Разрешить добавлять в корзину товары, у которых заполнены не все характеристики
                    "PRODUCT_PROPERTIES" => "", // Характеристики товара
                ),
                    false
                );?>

            </div>
<div class="offers__block offers__block-fast_goods">

                <? $GLOBALS["arrFilter"] = [
                    ">PROPERTY_CATCH" => date("Y-m-d"),
                    '!PROPERTY_ARCHIVE' => \Oneway\Constants::ID_PROP_ARCHIVE_YES
                ];?>

                <? $APPLICATION->IncludeComponent("oneway:catalog.section", "catch_index", Array(
                    "IBLOCK_TYPE" => "catalog", // Тип инфоблока
                    "IBLOCK_ID" => \Oneway\Constants::IBLOCK_CATALOG,   // Инфоблок
                    "SECTION_ID" => "", // ID раздела
                    "SECTION_CODE" => "",   // Код раздела
                    "SECTION_USER_FIELDS" => array( // Свойства раздела
                        0 => "",
                        1 => "",
                    ),
                    "ELEMENT_SORT_FIELD" => "PROPERTY_CATCH",   // По какому полю сортируем элементы
                    "ELEMENT_SORT_ORDER" => "asc",  // Порядок сортировки элементов
                    "ELEMENT_SORT_FIELD2" => "timestamp_x", // Поле для второй сортировки элементов
                    "ELEMENT_SORT_ORDER2" => "asc", // Порядок второй сортировки элементов
                    "FILTER_NAME" => "arrFilter",   // Имя массива со значениями фильтра для фильтрации элементов
                    "INCLUDE_SUBSECTIONS" => "Y",   // Показывать элементы подразделов раздела
                    "SHOW_ALL_WO_SECTION" => "Y",   // Показывать все элементы, если не указан раздел
                    "HIDE_NOT_AVAILABLE" => "Y",    // Не отображать товары, которых нет на складах
                    "PAGE_ELEMENT_COUNT" => "4",    // Количество элементов на странице
                    "LINE_ELEMENT_COUNT" => "1",    // Количество элементов выводимых в одной строке таблицы
                    "PROPERTY_CODE" => array(   // Свойства
                        0 => "",
                        1 => "",
                    ),
                    "OFFERS_LIMIT" => "0",  // Максимальное количество предложений для показа (0 - все)
                    "ADD_PICT_PROP" => "-",
                    "LABEL_PROP" => "-",
                    "PRODUCT_SUBSCRIPTION" => "N",  // Разрешить оповещения для отсутствующих товаров
                    "SHOW_DISCOUNT_PERCENT" => "N", // Показывать процент скидки
                    "SHOW_OLD_PRICE" => "Y",    // Показывать старую цену
                    "SHOW_CLOSE_POPUP" => "N",  // Показывать кнопку продолжения покупок во всплывающих окнах
                    "MESS_BTN_BUY" => "Купить", // Текст кнопки "Купить"
                    "MESS_BTN_ADD_TO_BASKET" => "В корзину",    // Текст кнопки "Добавить в корзину"
                    "MESS_BTN_SUBSCRIBE" => "Подписаться",  // Текст кнопки "Уведомить о поступлении"
                    "MESS_BTN_COMPARE" => "Сравнить",   // Текст кнопки "Сравнить"
                    "MESS_BTN_DETAIL" => "Подробнее",   // Текст кнопки "Подробнее"
                    "MESS_NOT_AVAILABLE" => "Нет в наличии",    // Сообщение об отсутствии товара
                    "SECTION_URL" => "",    // URL, ведущий на страницу с содержимым раздела
                    "DETAIL_URL" => "", // URL, ведущий на страницу с содержимым элемента раздела
                    "SECTION_ID_VARIABLE" => "SECTION_ID",  // Название переменной, в которой передается код группы
                    "AJAX_MODE" => "N", // Включить режим AJAX
                    "AJAX_OPTION_JUMP" => "N",  // Включить прокрутку к началу компонента
                    "AJAX_OPTION_STYLE" => "N", // Включить подгрузку стилей
                    "AJAX_OPTION_HISTORY" => "N",   // Включить эмуляцию навигации браузера
                    "CACHE_TYPE" => "A",    // Тип кеширования
                    "CACHE_TIME" => "36000000", // Время кеширования (сек.)
                    "CACHE_GROUPS" => "N",  // Учитывать права доступа
                    "SET_TITLE" => "N", // Устанавливать заголовок страницы
                    "SET_BROWSER_TITLE" => "N", // Устанавливать заголовок окна браузера
                    "SET_META_KEYWORDS" => "N", // Устанавливать ключевые слова страницы
                    "SET_META_DESCRIPTION" => "Y",  // Устанавливать описание страницы
                    "META_DESCRIPTION" => "-",  // Установить описание страницы из свойства
                    "ADD_SECTIONS_CHAIN" => "N",    // Включать раздел в цепочку навигации
                    "SET_STATUS_404" => "N",    // Устанавливать статус 404, если не найдены элемент или раздел
                    "CACHE_FILTER" => "Y",  // Кешировать при установленном фильтре
                    "ACTION_VARIABLE" => "action",  // Название переменной, в которой передается действие
                    "PRODUCT_ID_VARIABLE" => "id",  // Название переменной, в которой передается код товара для покупки
                    "PRICE_CODE" => array(  // Тип цены
                        0 => "BASE",
                    ),
                    "USE_PRICE_COUNT" => "N",   // Использовать вывод цен с диапазонами
                    "SHOW_PRICE_COUNT" => "1",  // Выводить цены для количества
                    "PRICE_VAT_INCLUDE" => "Y", // Включать НДС в цену
                    "CONVERT_CURRENCY" => "N",  // Показывать цены в одной валюте
                    "BASKET_URL" => "/personal/basket.php", // URL, ведущий на страницу с корзиной покупателя
                    "USE_PRODUCT_QUANTITY" => "N",  // Разрешить указание количества товара
                    "ADD_PROPERTIES_TO_BASKET" => "N",  // Добавлять в корзину свойства товаров и предложений
                    "ADD_TO_BASKET_ACTION" => "ADD",    // Показывать кнопку добавления в корзину или покупки
                    "DISPLAY_COMPARE" => "N",   // Разрешить сравнение товаров
                    "PAGER_TEMPLATE" => ".default", // Шаблон постраничной навигации
                    "DISPLAY_TOP_PAGER" => "N", // Выводить над списком
                    "DISPLAY_BOTTOM_PAGER" => "N",  // Выводить под списком
                    "PAGER_TITLE" => "Товары",  // Название категорий
                    "PAGER_SHOW_ALWAYS" => "N", // Выводить всегда
                    "PAGER_DESC_NUMBERING" => "N",  // Использовать обратную навигацию
                    "PAGER_DESC_NUMBERING_CACHE_TIME" => "36000",   // Время кеширования страниц для обратной навигации
                    "PAGER_SHOW_ALL" => "N",    // Показывать ссылку "Все"
                    "AJAX_OPTION_ADDITIONAL" => "", // Дополнительный идентификатор
                    "BROWSER_TITLE" => "-", // Установить заголовок окна браузера из свойства
                    "META_KEYWORDS" => "-", // Установить ключевые слова страницы из свойства
                    "PRODUCT_QUANTITY_VARIABLE" => "quantity",  // Название переменной, в которой передается количество товара
                    "PRODUCT_PROPS_VARIABLE" => "prop", // Название переменной, в которой передаются характеристики товара
                    "PARTIAL_PRODUCT_PROPERTIES" => "N",    // Разрешить добавлять в корзину товары, у которых заполнены не все характеристики
                    "PRODUCT_PROPERTIES" => "", // Характеристики товара
                ),
                    false
                );?>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

как вариант вызвать компоненты раньше и буферезировать их вывод, а в самих компонентах здель проверку есть ли елементы, а потом провереть есть ли в бувфере контент если есть выводить блок с содержимим буфера